# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined for React

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, api

Im attempting to access an array from my state in the App Component but I do not know why it doesn't work

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
//import Category from "./components/Category";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //const addon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=5")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        var arr = [];
        for (var x in data) {
          console.log(arr.push(data[x]));
          console.log(data[x]);
        }
        this.setState({
          categories: arr,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.categories[0].title}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

for context this is the JSON i am getting from the API

```js
[{"id":11531,"title":"mixed bag","clues_count":5},{"id":11532,"title":"let's \"ch\"at","clues_count":5},{"id":5412,"title":"prehistoric times","clues_count":10},{"id":11496,"title":"acting families","clues_count":5},{"id":11498,"title":"world city walk","clues_count":5}]
```

it seems like each object should have a title but js states otherwise

Answer (score 1):

as you are making a network call here and fetching data it will be a side effect (asynchronous call). so React life cycle progresses from componentDidMount() -> render() so meanwhile the `this.state.categories` will be of length 0 as you initialized it with an empty array.

To avoid such error, it's better to have conditional rendering like if the array is not empty then only render the title required.

```
 render() {
  return {this.state.categories.length>0 ? <div>{this.state.categories[0].title}</div> : null};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the application loads for the first time it doesn't have the content from the API yet and so you're trying to access the first element of an array which is empty. So even if the API call was quick there would always be one state in which this `categories` array will be empty. So in `render` method, you need to check if the array has some values.

```
render() {
    if (this.state.categories.length === 0) {
        return <div>No categories</div>
    }
    return <div>{this.state.categories[0].title}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: componentDidMount() happens before render() no? EDIT: Just tried it and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, but fetch is asynchronous and will always take more time (consider slow network, or even failed requests)

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //const addon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    fetch("http://jservice.io/api/categories?count=5")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let arr = Object.assign([], this.state.categories);
        arr = data;
        //the `data` you are getting is in an array.
        this.setState({
          categories: arr,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.categories && this.state.categories[0] && this.state.categories[0].title}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

When the component render, at that time the categories array in state is empty. And it tries to find the `title` key inside an empty array. That's why it's throwing the error.
Make sure to check for the conditions